# Need to find slow moving item from current stock and sale

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate slow and fast moving item based on the current stock and last 15 days sale. 
I will say my item as fast moving when 50% of stock is reduced (i.e) if sale >= current stock, then it is fast moving.
I will say my item as slow moving, when my sale is 15% of my stock, here I’m facing issue, bcoz when the item is returned, then my sale is -1 and if sale happen 1,so when i make sum of sale it is becoming 0. is there any way to ignore negative sale when making **sum of sale**.

```
item    sale    stock
a        1       5
a       -1       5
b        4       20
b        1       20
```

My query is

```
select item, sum(sale) as s, stock from sale table
group by item, stock
```

current output is

```
item    sale  stock
a        0     5
b        5     20
```

expected result is:

```
item    sale  stock
a        1     5
b        5     20
```

It should not consider negative sale or if it is negative then it should be 0 when making sum. please help me
and also when calculating percentage , I’m making `(sale/(sale+ava))*100` , when sale is '0' I’m getting error as zero cannot be divided, so is there any condition when sale is zero by default my sale percentage is "0"

Comment: please use text in the question next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use where clause to filter negative values

```
select item, sum(sale) as s, stock
from sale_table 
where (sale/nullif(sale,0))*100.00>.15
group by item, stock
```

Comment: Thank you Nick , how to calculate percentage of sale when sale is 0, I'm getting error: (sale/ sale + ava) * 100 in where condition to see only sale less than 15%.

Comment: @Angel, I've updated it for checking percentage - you can check now

Comment: This *feels* more complicated than it needs to be